# Why does the context menu take forever to open in Kdevelop?

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, troubleshooting, kate, kdevelop

I'm running Kdevelop 4.6.0 on Linux Mint 17.3, Mate. I've tried other version of Kdevelop but they have the same issue.

When you right click in Kdevelop to open a context menu, I can *literally* count slowly to 12 before the context menu opens. Every single time you open the context menu. Pressing the context menu key on the keyboard has the same effect.

How can I find the problem and fix it?

Comment: Did you check `top` or a similar tool to see what was happening?

Comment: Doesn't `top` just show CPU and memory usage?

Comment: Aren't those the first two things to check?

Comment: There's no CPU or memory spike when the context menu opens.

Comment: KDevelop 4.6 is **very** old. Can you try version 5?

Comment: I updated the whole computer to Mint 18.1 which is the most recent. The package manager version of Kdvelop is 4.7.3, I still have the issue, but the delay is shorter. Also, I noticed there is no delay when opening the context menu on local files, the long delay only occurs on files opened over sshfs. I'm not sure what it's doing over the network, but can it be disabled?